# Interpretation of regression coefficients obtained from applying left inverse of regressor matrix in an underdetermined system?

Tags: regression, linear-model, least-squares, matrix-inverse, underdetermined

If $X^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of $X$, $\beta = X^\dagger y$ is the least squares solution for $\beta$ when $y=X\beta$.

In the overdetermined case, applying $X^{\dagger,L} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ corresponds to the minimum norm residual (superscript $L$ used to indicate left inverse).

In the underdetermined case, applying $X^{\dagger,R} = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}$ corresponds to the minimum norm $\beta$ (superscript $R$ used to indicate right inverse).

If I solve for $\beta$ in an underdetermined system using $X^{\dagger,L}$ rather than $X^{\dagger,R}$, what does the solution correspond to, conceptually?

Comment: Your statement beginning "In the underdetermined case..." isn't quite right, as the minimum norm $\beta = 0$.  It's the minimum norm $\beta$ given that the norm of the residuals $= 0$.  Also note that in this case $(X^TX)^{-1}$ won't exist, as $X^TX$ won't be of full rank, so your question, at least as stated, has no answer as you can't in fact solve for $\beta$ in an underdetermined system using the left inverse.

Comment: Hm. The minimum norm $\beta$ that lies on the $y = X\beta$ hyperplane can't necessarily be zero? But you the second part of your answer makes sense. I was thinking that I found a least squares solution to a problem in R but with an iterative method; this does not correspond to the application of the left inverse... If you could move your comment to the answer section I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one. Many thanks